# How to fill a state with an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, use-state

I'm trying to add a list inside a state using the set method, but my state remains empty

App.js

```
// Starts the screts word game
  const startGame = () => {
    // pick word and pick category
    const { word, category } = pickWordAndCategory();
    // create array of letters
    let wordLetters = word.split("");
    wordLetters = wordLetters.map((l) => l.toLowerCase());

    // Fill states
    setPickedCategory(category);
    setPickedWord(word);
    setLettersList(wordLetters);
    console.log('wordLetters', wordLetters);
    console.log('lettersList', lettersList);
    

    setGameState(stages[1].name);
  };

  const pickWordAndCategory = () => {
    // pick a random category
    const categories = Object.keys(words);
    const category = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(categories).length)];
    console.log('category', category);

    // pick a random word
    const word = words[category][Math.floor(Math.random() * words[category].length)]
    console.log(word);

    return { word, category };
  }
```

[Here is the browser log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GCii.png)

When looking at the log we find our state empty

Comment: Sorry

I just updated the code

the state that is not being filled is the lettersList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `setLettersList(...)`, you are not actually changing `lettersList` variable itself. Notice how when you declare it, `const [lettersList, setLettersList] = useState([]);` `letterList` is actually constant, so that variable can't even be changed. Instead, it tells React to rerun the function component, this time giving `lettersList` the new value. Therefore, for the updated value, it will only come once  `const [lettersList, setLettersList] = useState([]);` is rerun again from the entire function being rerun again.

If you want to monitor changes to lettersList, you can do:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(lettersList);
}, [lettersList]);
```

This will print lettersList every time it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

States updates are asynchronous, so when you set a new state value and console.log() right after it, it's going to show the previous value, because the state hasn't been updated yet.

That's why your `lettersList` value show the old value of the state in the console (empty array).

Comment: Gustavo, Brasil aqui.

Obrigado pela ajuda! vou fazer os testes aqui